# Load chart from JSON - Change format of JSON array

Tags: javascript, json

I am using an example of a chart that gets the data from a JSON string. I am calculating the final JSON that the chart is going to use (called `data2`).

The issue is that I cannot use the array (`data2`) when I build the chart in the javascript section. It works fine as shown below in the snippet. What I need to do is to replace the static JSON after the 23d line of the JS script with the array `data2`. Here is the basic snippet I started working on :

```js
var json_data= {"headers":["Day","Hobby","Rate"],"rows":[["2017-10-16 00:00:00.0","beer",0.15824918844270675],["2017-10-16 00:00:00.0","push",0.10932372179344997],["2017-10-17 00:00:00.0","beer",0.16243707878321656],["2017-10-17 00:00:00.0","push",0.12342467710200489],["2017-10-18 00:00:00.0","beer",0.1701333117371019],["2017-10-18 00:00:00.0","push",0.13646302215695214],["2017-10-19 00:00:00.0","beer",0.1691911053818885],["2017-10-19 00:00:00.0","push",0.13529176147742863],["2017-10-20 00:00:00.0","push",0.12471145913670185],["2017-10-20 00:00:00.0","beer",0.16660114595720843],["2017-10-21 00:00:00.0","beer",0.1632134150509216],["2017-10-21 00:00:00.0","push",0.12104479125233003],["2017-10-22 00:00:00.0","push",0.11789599576807194],["2017-10-22 00:00:00.0","beer",0.15304531708971758],["2017-10-23 00:00:00.0","push",0.12068839662857922],["2017-10-23 00:00:00.0","beer",0.16865158102680616],["2017-10-24 00:00:00.0","beer",0.16968791058133556],["2017-10-24 00:00:00.0","push",0.12554102534428885],["2017-10-25 00:00:00.0","push",0.1277794674703459],["2017-10-25 00:00:00.0","beer",0.16345087602572633]]};

  var platform_data = json_data.rows; 
  var data2 = '[';
  var push_metric = 0;
  var beer_metric = 0;
  for (var i in platform_data)
 {
   var date = platform_data[i][0];
   if(platform_data[i][1] == 'push'){push_metric = (platform_data[i][2]*1000).toFixed(0)};
    if(platform_data[i][1] == 'beer'){beer_metric = (platform_data[i][2]*1000).toFixed(0)};
  data2+='{ day: "'+ date+'", '+ 'pushups: '+ push_metric +', '+ 'beers: '+ beer_metric+'},';
 }
  data2+= ']';      



new Morris.Line({
  // ID of the element in which to draw the chart.
  element: "pushups",
  // Chart data records -- each entry in this array corresponds to a point on
  // the chart.
  data: [{ day: "2017-10-16 00:00:00.0", pushups: 0, beers: 158},{ day: "2017-10-16 00:00:00.0", pushups: 109, beers: 158},{ day: "2017-10-17 00:00:00.0", pushups: 109, beers: 162},{ day: "2017-10-17 00:00:00.0", pushups: 123, beers: 162},{ day: "2017-10-18 00:00:00.0", pushups: 123, beers: 170},{ day: "2017-10-18 00:00:00.0", pushups: 136, beers: 170},{ day: "2017-10-19 00:00:00.0", pushups: 136, beers: 169},{ day: "2017-10-19 00:00:00.0", pushups: 135, beers: 169},{ day: "2017-10-20 00:00:00.0", pushups: 125, beers: 169},{ day: "2017-10-20 00:00:00.0", pushups: 125, beers: 167},{ day: "2017-10-21 00:00:00.0", pushups: 125, beers: 163},{ day: "2017-10-21 00:00:00.0", pushups: 121, beers: 163},{ day: "2017-10-22 00:00:00.0", pushups: 118, beers: 163},{ day: "2017-10-22 00:00:00.0", pushups: 118, beers: 153},{ day: "2017-10-23 00:00:00.0", pushups: 121, beers: 153},{ day: "2017-10-23 00:00:00.0", pushups: 121, beers: 169},{ day: "2017-10-24 00:00:00.0", pushups: 121, beers: 170},{ day: "2017-10-24 00:00:00.0", pushups: 126, beers: 170},{ day: "2017-10-25 00:00:00.0", pushups: 128, beers: 170},{ day: "2017-10-25 00:00:00.0", pushups: 128, beers: 163},],
  // The name of the data record attribute that contains x-values.
  xkey: "day",
  parseTime: false,
  // A list of names of data record attributes that contain y-values.
  ykeys: ["pushups", "beers"],
  // Labels for the ykeys -- will be displayed when you hover over the
  // chart.
  labels: ["Pushups", "Beers"],
  lineColors: ["#373651", "#E65A26"]
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #E0E2DD;
  font-family: helvetica, open-sans;
}

.graph-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 750px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.graph {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 750px;
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://stevenlevithan.com/assets/misc/date.format.js"></script>
<div class='graph-wrapper'>
  <div class='graph' id='pushups'></div>
</div>
```

And I am focusing on the issue which is the format of the JSON array. More specifically, in the snippet below, I have both arrays. I only need to change the syntax (remove the quotes from each object) I guess. Unless there is another easier solution:

```js
var json_data= {"headers":["Day","Hobby","Rate"],"rows":[["2017-10-16 00:00:00.0","beer",158],["2017-10-16 00:00:00.0","pushup",109],["2017-10-17 00:00:00.0","beer",162],["2017-10-17 00:00:00.0","pushup",123],["2017-10-18 00:00:00.0","beer",170],["2017-10-18 00:00:00.0","pushup",136],["2017-10-19 00:00:00.0","beer",169],["2017-10-19 00:00:00.0","pushup",135],]};

  var platform_data = json_data.rows; 
  var pushup_metric = 0;
  var beer_metric = 0;
 var data2 = [];
 
  
  for (var i in platform_data)
 {
   var date = platform_data[i][0];
   if(platform_data[i][1] == 'push'){pushup_metric = platform_data[i][1]};
    if(platform_data[i][1] == 'beer'){beer_metric = platform_data[i][2]};
    object = '{ day: "'+ date+'", '+ '"pushups": '+ pushup_metric +', '+ '"beers": '+ beer_metric+'}';
  data2.push(object);
 }
  

var data = [{ day: "2017-10-16 00:00:00.0", pushups: 0, beers: 158},{ day: "2017-10-16 00:00:00.0", pushups: 109, beers: 158},{ day: "2017-10-17 00:00:00.0", pushups: 109, beers: 162},{ day: "2017-10-17 00:00:00.0", pushups: 123, beers: 162},{ day: "2017-10-18 00:00:00.0", pushups: 123, beers: 170},{ day: "2017-10-18 00:00:00.0", pushups: 136, beers: 170},{ day: "2017-10-19 00:00:00.0", pushups: 136, beers: 169},{ day: "2017-10-19 00:00:00.0", pushups: 135, beers: 169},];

  console.log(data);
 

 console.log(data2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.2/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.0/morris.min.js"></script>



<div id='data2'></div> <br><br> 

<div id='data1'></div> <br><br>
```

Comment: could you please post the relevant code without any parts to be ignored? :)

Comment: Why do you build a JSON String by concatenating strings... JS can natively work with JSON. Whyyyy do you do like `data2 += "{...}"` work with objects, use a real array like `data2.push({day: 12, pushups: 69});`

Comment: `What I need to do is to replace the static JSON after the 25th line of the JS script with the variable data2.` what do you mean? 25th line of code? 25th entry of `rows`?

Comment: @DanFromGermany Question updated. I just need to manipulate the JSON for now. Unless there is another solution. I need to remove the double quotes from each object when I push the objects in the array.

Comment: You don't have to use quotes at all when you build an object. Compare your code to this: `object = { day: date, pushups: pushup_metric, ...};` no quotes, plain javascript.

Comment: Oh yes. You can post it as an answer. I thought there was another issue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try to "build" Javascript objects using strings and string concatenation.

Simply push objects to arrays and work with JSON:

```
object = { day: date, pushups: pushup_metric, ...};
date2.push(object);
```